What are these mysterious users that have permission?

It seems to exist in accounts I just created too.
Also the only way to properly delete them is to propagate permissions to children and then delete.
Otherwise I will get can't enumerate something.


Ever have the drive mounted on a different Windows install?

The users don’t exist on the system so while they have access the users themselves don’t exist. Feel free to remove the permissions. Why are you view the permissions of a User profile directory as something other than the user “coding”

Based on the permissions the only way they would have access is if you granted those users, which do not exist on your system, access to the user. The username suggests your trying to use it as a shared location by chance? You also don't indicate what user you are trying change the permissions of a user profile as, by default, not even an Administrator should be doing that. changing the permissions of a user profile is a VERY bad idea. You have been warned

Quite easy to find:
regedit -> open HKEY_USERS.
From there the you can check SID's (those numerical user accounts, source: M$ docs ):

the long ones belong to normal accounts (and as far as I can see that's the 2nd case here), and if you navigate to "volatile environment" (as shown below) - you'll get usernames and folders:


As linked documentation explains, the "short" ones in my picture are valid system accounts:

S-1-5-18: System (or LocalSystem)
S-1-5-19: NT Authority (LocalService)
S-1-5-20: Network Service

In your case the second one, S-1-5-21-153XXX is gonna be a standard user with admin privileges, you'll find his name in "volatile environment"
The first one, S-1-15-3-655XXXX is so called "capability SID" - let me quote a few words from other M$ documentation:

Capability SIDs uniquely and immutably identify capabilities. In this
context, a capability is an unforgeable token of authority that grants
a Windows component or a Universal Windows Application access to
resources such as documents, cameras, locations, and so forth. An
application that "has" a capability is granted access to the resource
that is associated with the capability.

I've never actually seen a capability SID on any of my systems, so I can't tell you if "volatile environment" will be present, but "Environment" should be.
